# how can I apply coloring existing coloring templates for a proprietary markup for c9.io

Tags: ide, cloud9-ide

I have a file that is XML like but, unlike with sublime, I cannot select and apply a template that best handles it with colors.

Now I just get a bunch of monochrome text.

Is there a way to:

a) apply an existing template?
b) work in a synchronized fashion with own local editor?

Answer (score 0):

In cloud9 You can pick a syntax from `View > Syntax` menu, or by clicking on the syntax name in statusbar.